# Create a 'trapezium' shaped div with Clipped overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im wondering if anybody know if at all possible, how to create a trapezium using CSS/Html/Canvas.

I've tried to sort of hash one together only its very messy and would be unusable in the real world.

```
div {
 width:0;
 margin-left:-1000px;
 height:100px; 
 border-right:1000px solid lightblue;
 border-top:60px solid transparent;
 border-bottom:60px solid transparent; 
 padding-left:1000px;
 white-space:no-wrap;
}
```

Heres my jsFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/Liamatvenn/WWYYM/

Comment: Why is what you've done unusable?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Your fiddle appears to be doing what you're looking for.

Comment: @sn3ll: What the OP wants is for the text content to "clip" (be hidden) when flowing outside the trapezoid shape.

Comment: It's unusable because the sizes have to be static, and they're tedious to change (not simply width+height here).

Answer (score 1):

I can do it with 2 extra divs as wrappers.

CSS

```
.trapezium {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(6deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.trapezium > div {
  background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-12deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.trapezium > div > div {
  font-size: 60px;
  background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: -30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(6deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/Q4gxF/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Vals, I think this is as close as I'll get, may have to use some .pngs as its also going to be a fluid site - just wanted to question if its possible, appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

i don`t know what you want. so i guess this will help you little.

```
  div {
   width:0;
   margin-left:-100px;
   height:100px; 
   border-right:100px solid lightblue;
   border-top:60px solid transparent;
   border-bottom:60px solid transparent; 
   padding-left:100px;
   white-space:no-wrap;
 }
```

Comment: A `div` is `display: block` by default, so this does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you speaking for something like this please ? Check this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/WWYYM/3/ . Let me know if it works for you. I have edited your code like the following:

```
div {
  border-bottom: 100px solid lightblue;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 500px;
  white-space:no-wrap;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can addition transform alike below:

```
div {
width:0;
margin-left:-50px;
margin-top: -500px;
height:100px;
border-right:100px solid lightblue;
border-top:60px solid transparent;
border-bottom:60px solid transparent;
padding-left:1000px;
white-space:no-wrap;

transform:rotate(20deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(20deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
```

}